# Do native speakers pronounce "found the remark" without the "the"?

Tags: listening

> Haley **found the remark** disrespectful and felt she couldn't keep quiet,
>   the sources said.

I heard someone read this, and I can hardly hear "the" between "found" and "remark".

Comment: The reason you can hardly hear "the" between "found" and "remark" is because in many relaxed casual speech contexts it's ***hardly there*** - the vowel itself would often be reduced to an almost inaudible schwa (neutral vowel). Note that in your *exact* context, all native speakers (and *listeners*) would "know" the article was present *because it's syntactically necessary*. On the other hand, if I were to say *I found the three things you were looking for,* the article might or might not be present, so even native speakers might not be *certain* whether I'd actually enunciated it or not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: however, while *I found three things* and *I found the three things* are both grammatical, they are not synonymous.  The first implies that there was an unspecified number of things you were looking for (and you found 3 on the list), the second implies that you found those the precise three things you were looking for.

Comment: @poncho: Exactly my point! If the person I was speaking to was actually looking for *four* things, he might be uncertain as to whether ***I*** mistakenly thought I was only trying to find three anyway, and had prematurely given up the hunt. He might therefore have to check with something like *What about [thing4]? You do realise I'm looking for that too, don't you?*

Comment: I just read that aloud myself and noticed I blended the "the" and "remark" together, i.e. "theremark".

Comment: Many non-native speakers have trouble ending on a consonant, and will pronounce 'found' as 'found-uh' - which is exactly how a native speaker would pronounce 'found the'. Perhaps you heard 'found-uh remark' and interpreted it as  'found remark' instead of 'found the remark'?

Comment: @Sanchises Then, does the consonant 'ð' sound of **the** disappear in such a way of native English speakers' pronunciation? Furthermore, is 'ð' sound also left out in **MooseBoys**'s way of pronuncing the words? I would really appreciate it if you give an answer to this.

Comment: @SmartHumanism I'd rather say that the 'd' of 'found' disappears, although when speaking quickly it may not make much of a difference. Either way, the 'd' and 'ð' definitely blend into a single consonant.

Comment: @Sanchises Thank you for answering. Then, how about the tongue and mouth movement when making 'th' sound there? How being 'th' sound is clear than being 'd' sound? Does the movement also blend with the movement for 'd' so that the movement is formed in the middle of two different sound movements? I'd like to get the insights into making the sound, rather than listening.

Comment: @SmartHumanism You should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

*"Haley **found remark** disrespectful" is ungrammatical, so you'd be unlikely to hear a native speaker say it.

What you're likely hearing is the "the" being reduced, likely with almost no vowel sound. Sometimes the "th" might sound more like a "d", as well.

e.g., a native speaker might *pronounce* it like either of the following, in casual speech:

> Haley found th' remark disrespectful
>
> Haley found d' remark disrespectful

In such cases, I'd often expect the first "e" in "remark" and/or "disrespectful" to be heavily reduced, as well.

In extreme cases, you might even get the "d" in "found" dropped, so under the right circumstance, you could have a pronunciation which sounds like:

> Haley foun' d'remark disr'spectful

Where "d'remark" would be "the remark" in well-enunciated speech, and "foun'" would be "found".

Comment: Yes, it's ungrammatical. I was practice my Enlgish-listening when I heard that. I also found it was strange, and couldn't understand the sentence. I replayed it many times, counldn't figure it out. Then, I looked up the sentence, That I found there was a "the".

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the reduced "the" is probably enhanced by the final "d" in found. The tongue doesn't have to move far to turn a "d" into a "th", so it's easy to chain "found" and "the" -- in fact that pair is probably most often pronounced "foun the". Try this with "blame the receptionist" -- the "the" will be perfectly audible.

Comment: It might help the asker to mention that quiet, short pronunciation of “the” is quite common. They are likely to encounter this again.

Comment: Your last one is fairly extreme, but apparently I do part of that: "Foun' the remark", I don't blend "the" into "remark".

Comment: @BallpointBen So when it is reduced, is there any case the tongue doesn't move as in making 'th' sound, and just make only 'd' sound? Or is it more common that the 'd' sound is left out and only the 'th' sound survives?

Comment: @SmartHumanism No. "Found [th]e" would be pronounced as "found a", which would be interpreted as in e.g., "I found a dollar on the ground". You need to pronounce the "th" so that it's understood as "found the" instead of "found a".

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you for answering. So, to sum it up, generally speaking, native English speakers are likely to pronounce 'th' sound other than 'd' sound, when 'th' and 'd' together are reduced. And they make the physical movement of their tongue and mouth of 'th' sound other than the movement of 'd' sound.

Answer (score 41):

I'm a native English speaker, and we do say the "The"

It's true that if you are speaking quickly it will all get blended together, but we definitely don't omit it.

Comment: Yes The the dental [d] at the end of "found" will blend with the dental fricative of "the", and the vowel sound is a schwa, so pretty minimal already.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely possible to come out like "Haley founthuhremark" but the "the" is still there

Comment: And, native speakers will often be happy to formally correct and/or enunciate clearer when misunderstood.  While it might sound like "Haley foun-der-mark" and that's what they are saying, if asked, most will slow down and enunciate every syllable of each word, going back to what would be written and then say "Haley... found ... the... remark".

Answer (score 12):

In my dialect (British, West Midlands), it actually comes out as:

*"Hayley foun' the remark disrespectful."*

The D in found is very, very heavily reduced in this sentence. In fact, forcing myself to enunciate the D as well as the "The" seems really unnatural. Perhaps this is why a non-native speaker could miss the different sounds?

But regardless, the grammatically correct sentence definitely includes the "the" and I can't imagine somebody omitting the word fully even in casual speech.

Comment: Yes, the British accent is more clearly. But, unfortunately, by watching so many American TV series, and moives. I'm just accustomed to the American English. DX

Comment: It's required because the most likely correct alternative is "a remark", a very different thing. I suggest that's why you're uncomfortable with leaving out the article altogether.

Comment: "Trouble at mill"... (no apostrophe)  Yorkshire might drop it. Strine (Aus) would blend it "Garna footy Sadee?" for "Are you going to the football on Saturday ?"  "found the remark" as "founder a mark" unless delivered at a word by word pace.

Comment: American English here. I pronounce it the same way.

Answer (score 9):

Native speakers don't "omit" the entire word, but many of them will strongly de-emphasize the vowel sound in *the* and essentially merge it with the start of the next word. It's not quite an elision of the syllable, because you can still hear it, but it's very fast and *nearly* omitted.

Typically this happens if the following word starts with an unstressed syllable. For example, a native speaker would likely sound like they were saying:

*I found the entire exchange disrespectful.*

or:

*I found the statement disrespectful.*

but:

*I found th'remark disrespectful.*

Answer (score 7):

Others have already given good answers, but for what it is worth, I'm an U.S. speaker and would naturally say

"*Haley foun' the remark disrespectful*"

just like @Psiloc mentioned. But I would guess many Americans would also say

"*Haley foun da remark disrespectful*"

where "the" almost sounds like "da" attached to "found".

Comment: Might even come out as blended as "founder mark" when said fast.  Though ask most Americans to slow down, they will enunciate every syllable and word, and enunciate "the".

Answer (score 4):

To add to the dialect versions, northern English dialects will often pronounce "the remark" as "ut-remark" with a glottal stop (spelled "t'remark" if you want to write it down). This is very easy to mishear.

It's standard for Yorkshire, parts of Lancashire, and parts of Derbyshire. You won't hear it further south, and when you get further north (up into Cumbria, Northumberland and Tyneside) then you have different accents again which also don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

We definitely say it. As other answers have pointed out, the 'd' and the 'th' can get blended together, and the 'e' doesn't have much emphasis on it. But you can always hear the syllable, no matter how mangled the pronunciation is. Put simply, no matter how fast we're speaking, it takes us longer to say "found the remark" than "found remark".

Comment: The presence of the extra syllable does not really force the whole phrase to take longer, English being a stress-timed language.

Comment: You can tell me about stress-timed languages all day, and I still won't be able to say "found the remark" faster than "found remark".

Comment: I didn’t say *faster*. I said that it may well be the *same* length.

Comment: All right, damn you: You can tell me about stress-timed languages all day and I still won't be able to say "found the remark" **as fast as** "found remark".

Answer (score 3):

It's been obliquely mentioned a few times here, but I thought it might be worth spelling out:

Not only is ***the*** reduced to ***th'*** when a native-speaker says this, but ***found*** is also reduced to ***foun'***.  A native-speaker will typically pronounce the **D** on "found" only if the following word begins with a vowel.

So when you're listening, you're merging ***foun'*** with ***th'*** to make something like ***founth*** (which sounds very much like ***found***), and therefore it sounds to you like there is no ***the***.

A native speaker would pronounce "found remark" as "foun' remark", and there would be no **d/th** sound between the words.

Comment: Mostly right but I think the final sentence is wholly wrong.  When speaking, the 'd' sound might get pushed onto the second word but it wouldn't be dropped.

Answer (score 2):

What you are hearing as the end of "found" it actually the "the". The part that most likely is being omitted is the 'd' in "found". Like "foun the remark"

Comment: it seems so

https://forvo.com/phrase/they_found_the_mummified_body_of_an_egyptian_pharaoh./

Answer (score 0):

In my dialect (mid-southern american) we tend to pronounce it like "found th'remark".

Answer (score 0):

Subtle differences in the sounds formed are not necessarily conveyed to the listener. Try this test:

Choose a quiet place and native speaker. Speak the word **facts** then the word **fax**.

I tried this and my mouth formed the two words differently, but the listener could not hear the difference.

So although I would pronounce the phrase **foun' d-th' remark**, the listener will not hear the subtle changes the mouth makes switching from **d** to **th**.

Answer (score -1):

No, the word "the" would not be omitted in that phrase. It sounds like they were just speaking quickly.

Comment: You downvoters aren't native English speakers, are you?